# Why can't I pass Clojurescript functions as callbacks to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, clojurescript

I'm trying to use Google's recaptcha in a Clojurescript/Reagent SPA as seen in the code below.

```
(ns myapp.captcha
  (:require  [reagent.core :as r]
             [cljs.core.async :refer [<! >! chan]])
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go go-loop]]))

(def captcha-ch (chan))

(defn ^:export data-callback [human-proof]
  (go (>! captcha-ch {:captcha-data human-proof})))

(defn ^:export data-expired-callback []
  (go (>! captcha-ch {:captcha-expired true})))

(defn captcha [site-key]
  (let [grecaptcha-script (doto (.createElement js/document "script")
                            (.setAttribute "id" "grecaptcha-script")
                            (.setAttribute "src" "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"))
        out-ch (chan)
        comp (r/create-class
              {:component-did-mount (fn [this]
                                      (.appendChild (.-body js/document)
                                                    grecaptcha-script))
               :component-will-unmount (fn [this]
                                         (.removeChild (.-body js/document)
                                                       (.getElementById js/document "grecaptcha-script"))
                                         (go (>! captcha-ch {:exit true})))
               :reagent-render (fn [this]
                                 [:div.g-recaptcha
                                  {:data-sitekey site-key
                                   :data-callback "myapp.captcha.data_callback"
                                   :data-expired-callback "myapp.captcha.data_expired_callback"}])})]
    (go-loop []
      (let [msg (<! captcha-ch)]
        (if-not (:exit msg)
          (>! out-ch msg)
          (recur))))

    {:chan out-ch :comp comp}))
```

When the captcha is solved and data-callback is supposed to be called I get an error saying:

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function:
>   myapp.captcha.data_callback

On the other hand if I call myapp.captcha.data_callback from the browser's debugger console the function is visible and executes correctly.

PS: For now please ignore the global chan, which is a different matter. In order to fix that I have to call captcha render explicitly and that puts me in some race conditions apparently related to the order of script loading. I admit that it might be a cleaner approach but for now it's interesting to see what the problem is here.

Comment: Have you tried "myapp.captcha.data-callback" rather than the underscore version? Have you tried it with your namespace just being "callback" i.e. without any namespace issues, that could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your question. Yes. I tried with & without namespace but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Closure compiler obfuscates your code during compilation, including renaming your functions. The easiest solution is first ensuring the compiler optimization respects your function names (or simply disabling the optimization such as via `:optimization :none` with shadow cljs.

Next, you want to make sure the function you want to use is exported. This is done with `^:export`, such as:
`(defn ^:export my-exported-fun [] ...)`

Lastly, pass the full namespace when refering to the function, such as `myapp.frontend.my-exported-fun`.

Hope this helps the future travelers :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround but it's a bit of a hack.

I added a script element just before recaptcha script. In this script element I define callbacks which forward the calls to my clojurescript functions.

See the code below.

Still it would be nice to understand why I can't use my Clojurescript callbacks directly.

```
(defn captcha [handler]
  (let [callback-hooks (let [s (.createElement js/document "script")]
                         (.setAttribute s "id" "captcha-callbacks")
                         (set! (.-text s)
                               (str "var captcha_data_callback = function(x) { myapp.captcha.data_callback(x)};"
                                    "var captcha_data_expired_callback = function() { myapp.captcha.data_expired_callback()};"))
                         s)
        grecaptcha-script (doto (.createElement js/document "script")
                            (.setAttribute "id" "grecaptcha-script")
                            (.setAttribute "src" "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"))
        captcha-div [:div.g-recaptcha
                     {:data-sitekey config/grecaptcha-client-key
                      :data-callback "captcha_data_callback"
                      :data-expired-callback "captcha_data_expired_callback"}]]

    (go-loop []
      (let [msg (<! captcha-ch)]
        (handler msg)

        (if-not (:end msg)
          (recur))))

    (r/create-class
     {:component-did-mount (fn [this]
                             (doto (.-body js/document)
                               (.appendChild callback-hooks)
                               (.appendChild grecaptcha-script)))
      :component-will-unmount (fn [this]
                                (doto (.-body js/document)
                                  (.removeChild (.getElementById js/document "captcha-callbacks"))
                                  (.removeChild (.getElementById js/document "grecaptcha-script")))
                                (go (>! captcha-ch {:end true})))
      :reagent-render (fn [this] captcha-div)})))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation as you and have only been able to solve it in the way that you listed - by supplying a JS script that passes the function call along to CLJS.

But, I found out though that if you define a callback function as an object property (in JS) Recaptcha is still unable to find that function, even though the function does exist.

I define a script tag in the the `<head>` of my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This function will be called correctly when the captcha is loaded
  var onloadCallback = function() { myapp.captcha.onloadCallback() };
  // This function will not be found by recaptcha.js
  var testObject = { onDataCallback: function(x) { myapp.captcha.onDataCallback(x) };
</script>
```

So with that in mind, it seems that the issue is not a ClojureScript problem, but a recaptcha problem. If there was a way to export ClojureScript functions directly into the global scope outside of their namespace (I'm not sure if this is possible), then in theory you should be able to access your CLJS callbacks directly from recaptcha.

Hope this helps!